# Issue upgrading Flink 1.8.0 to 1.11.2

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink, hadoop-yarn

We are facing an issue while upgrading Flink 1.8.0 to 1.11.2. We are able to run successfully a few examples of code given by Flink like wordcount and window join. We are using Flink with Yarn.

Our job gets stuck in an accepted state with the message "AM container is launched, waiting for AM container to Register with RM". We are using dependencies used by the above example code with other dependencies required by my code. We have more than enough resources in the yarn queue.

Using this command to submit job :

```
/home/hdfs/flink-1.11.2/bin/flink run -m yarn-cluster -p 4 -yjm 8096m -ytm 8098m -c test.StreamJob -jar /tmp/stream.jar --config ./config.json > ./test_bkt.log
```

Comment: What happens if you give something more like 2GB (`-yjm 2048m`) to the Job Manager?

Comment: The way that memory/heap gets configured has changed since 1.8. If you haven't updated your flink-conf.yaml file that might explain what the job doesn't start. And filesystems and metrics reporters are now loaded differently (as plugins). And hadoop is managed a bit differently as well. The logs may give some clues.